# Solving ODE with time varying parameter using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

My aim is to solve a system of differential equations using Rcpp. Basically I want to set up a system as shown in the code below (modification of the code example found here: [How to use C++ ODE solver with Rcpp in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044530/how-to-use-c-ode-solver-with-rcpp-in-r)).

At the moment the code below integrates a set of odes in the time intervall 0 to 10. For the entire time params[0] is -100, and parms[1] = 10. However, my aim is to set up a system where parms[0] and parms[1] are only constant over a subset of the time intervall. E.g. for the time intervall 0-5 parms[0] should be set to 1 and for the remaining time parms[0]should be 10.

Actually, I have almost no experience in c++/rcpp. Thus, I have no idea how to set up such a system. Could you please give me a hint how I should construct the ode system. Thank you very much in advance for any advice how to solve this problem.

i save the code below in a cpp file and call it with sourceCpp in R:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef boost::array< double ,3 > state_type;
typedef boost::array< double ,2 > parms_type;

double time = 10;
parms_type parms = {-100, 10};

void rhs( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double t) {
dxdt[0] = parms[0]/(2.0*t*t) + x[0]/(2.0*t);
dxdt[1] = parms[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
dxdt[2] = parms[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
}

void write_cout( const state_type &x , const double t ) {
// use Rcpp's stream
Rcpp::Rcout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2] <<  endl;
}

typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type > stepper_type;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool boostExample() {
state_type x = { 1.0 , 1.0, 1.0 }; // initial conditions
integrate_adaptive(make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type () ) ,
                 rhs , x , 1.0 , time, 0.1 , write_cout );
return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the necessary includes etc. to make this question independent of the reference.

Comment: sorry i didn't get the point? what should I do?

Comment: The referenced question contains all the `include` statements that are  necessary to compile the code. At least for the `rcpp` tag it is customary to post code that can be compiled right away. So please [edit] your question to include the necessary headers. In general it is also good to add a special `/*** R ... */` comment block that shows how the functions are used from R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile for me:

```
boost-ode.cpp:11:8: error: ‘double time’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 double time = 10.0;
        ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/unordered_map:41,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from boost-ode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/time.h:192:15: note: previous declaration ‘time_t time(time_t*)’
 extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
               ^~~~
```

I simply removed the global variable `time` and used an explicit `10.0` in it's place. I also removed the namespace usage of `Rcpp` and `std`. The former was not used anyway, the latter only in one place. Generally I try to avoid importing such large namespaces, especially two at the same time.

Anyway, one simple solution would be to introduce two param vectors and select in `rhs` the appropriate one based on the time:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef boost::array< double ,3 > state_type;
typedef boost::array< double ,2 > parms_type;

parms_type parms_begin = {1, 10};
parms_type parms_end = {10, 10};

void rhs( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double t) {
  if (t < 5.0) {
    dxdt[0] = parms_begin[0]/(2.0*t*t) + x[0]/(2.0*t);
    dxdt[1] = parms_begin[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
    dxdt[2] = parms_begin[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
  } else {
    dxdt[0] = parms_end[0]/(2.0*t*t) + x[0]/(2.0*t);
    dxdt[1] = parms_end[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
    dxdt[2] = parms_end[1]/(2.0*t*t) + x[1]/(2.0*t);
  }
}

void write_cout( const state_type &x , const double t ) {
  // use Rcpp's stream
  Rcpp::Rcout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2] <<  std::endl;
}

typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type > stepper_type;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool boostExample() {
  state_type x = { 1.0 , 1.0, 1.0 }; // initial conditions
  integrate_adaptive(make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type () ) ,
                     rhs , x , 1.0 , 10.0, 0.1 , write_cout );
  return true;
}
/*** R
boostExample()
*/
```

Comment: @Hugo You are welcome. feel free to accept/up-vote the answer as you see fit.